# When to use Windows Store app?

Tags: winforms, windows-store-apps

I have a winforms application and was wondering whether I should attempt to move it to Windows store app (and WPF) or not. I would expect metro style apps to have the same potential as desktop apps, but what got me wondering is the fact that VS 2012 is not a metro app. It doesn't really surprise me much as every metro app I've seen so far look like a phone app that can't really do much and I can't imagine how VS would look like as a metro app.

Seems to me like Microsoft wants to slowly move everything to metro, otherwise I don't see the point on introducing a whole new visual experience just to get stuck with having to switch between metro and desktop, but even Notepad is still a desktop application. So my question is, basically, is every kind of application supposed to be movable to metro or is metro only for small phone-like applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metro-style apps are for content consumption, like you would find on a tablet.

Classical desktop apps are for content creation.

Comment: I think this defines Metro too narrowly. It would be like saying that classical desktop apps are for content creation, while _websites_ are for content consumption; all of us experience a large number of websites that behave like applications: SO, Gmail, Amazon, eBay, etc.

Comment: -1. Definitely not true. Especially when the machines run with a keyboard and a mouse attached.

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe that Microsoft is intending every application to end up Metro.  I see more lightweight types apps going to Metro. Heavy duty line-of-business apps will stay on the desktop side of things.

I do see an opportunity for writing both desktop and Metro style apps in enterprise environments though.  Imagine this hypothetical scenario:

In an enterprise, I can see Accounts Receivable running the full-blown, monolithic, desktop application on their desktops just like they run them under Win7 because they’re needs are pretty extensive.

The receptionist will run a touch enabled laptop with a Metro app that is tied into just the corporate appointments.

The guys on the loading dock will be running Win8 phones that have the intake/outtake app showing schedules for deliveries and what not.

Managers and executives have Metro tablets that have an app that shows metrics: lots of pretty charts and graphs showing the current condition of what and how the company is operating in it’s different lines of business.

For the users that need the complexity, it’s desktop mode, but for the users that perform smaller, specific computer tasks, touch-enabled Metro apps for them.

Answer (score 1):

I think metro apps are an additional feature and I do not think, that they are a serious replacement for desktop applications. If you want to deploy your apps to tablet PCs, phones or any other touchscreen/handheld devices, metro style would be a good choice. At the moment there are just not many consumers for metro apps as Windows 8 has not even come to the markets.

As you already mentioned, on desktop PCs metro apps are very uncomfortable and do not provide the full functionality as desktop applications can do.

> So my question is, basically, is every kind of application supposed to be movable to metro or is metro only for small phone-like applications?

I don't think so, as this means automatically that many customers who have used previous versions of Windows would have to learn working with the metro interface.

Metro apps provide much more functionality than desktop gadgets have done in Vista, as they can be programmed using C# or other .Net languages, but metro apps use up too much space to be controlled with a simple mouse.

Comment: *Windows 8 has not even reached beta status* care to link a source? There are release candidates of Windows8 and there's been over 6 months of beta before that. Windows8 is the future, don't program in the past.

Comment: Alright, I have changed it, I had been confused by the names developer and consumer preview. Is this the only reason for your down vote, or are you too emotional?

Comment: Nah that was it, I removed it.